# Reverting commits on remote branch

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I made two commits to my Master branch that were then pushed to the remote branch.

I've now decided to go back to my original code before those two commits and so selected my original commit with Reset Master to Commit (using SourceTree). I then made a few changes and committed these.

The problem is when I try to push to the remote it tells me I need to fetch first. I could get around this with a Force Push but I'd like to keep my commit history.

Is this possible without making a new branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `git revert` to undo the commits you want to remove in a way that documents the fact you're undoing them, then merge or rebase.

**Details**

In order to keep your history as easy to understand as possible in the future, I would first revert the two commits you don't want to keep, on the master branch.

Since you have commits on your local `master` branch you want to keep, I'm going to temporarily create another branch off of `origin/master` to make things simplest.

```sh
git checkout origin/master
git checkout -b dev.about-to-revert
```

Now, create "revert" commits to undo the two commits you don't want to keep:

```sh
git revert <commit to revert>
git revert <commit to revert>
```

From the [git revert manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert): "Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them."

So now branch `dev.about-to-revert` has the same code as `origin/master` before the two commits, and you can either rebase or merge in your new work.

Rebase:

```
git checkout master
git rebase dev.about-to-revert
```

Or merge

```
git checkout master
git merge dev.about-to-revert
```

Or merge the other way if you prefer having the parents of the merge in the other direction:

```
git merge master
git checkout master
git merge dev.about-to-revert
```

And now you're done with `dev.about-to-revert` so you can get rid of it:

```
git branch -d dev.about-to-revert
```

**PS**: you asked "Is this possible without creating a new branch". I assume you don't want to push a new branch on the remote, but that it's still OK to create one temporarily in your sandbox. There are ways to do the same operations I show here without a new branch, doing the reverts on a detached HEAD, but it's simpler as shown here.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a merge revision..... *with a twist*: you will have to ask git to *really* skip the merge and keep content as it is in your *local* branch so that git can understand that you actually took content back.

```
git commit-tree -m "Merging so that I can keep the revisions I reverted" -p HEAD -p origin/master HEAD^{tree}
```

So, you are creating a new merge revision that will have as parents your current local revision/branch and what is on the remote branch. It will keep the *tree* (files and their contents) as they are in your *local* branch. This will print an ID to a revision. Take a look at it in gitk or `git log` or checkout the revision and make sure everything looks right. If that's the case, then put the branch on that revision:

```
# if you didn't checkout the revision run the following command
git merge the-id-we-are-talking-about
```

Or

```
# if you did checkout the revision, then let's put the branch where we are right now
git branch -f master # set master where we are
git checkout master
```

After you have run either of those two commands, depending on where you were and stuff, now you can push your local master

```
git push
```

Comment: This is a decent solution, but it would make the history quite hard to understand. I would recommend using git revert to undo the "bad" commit, and then doing a normal merge or rebase, so there is an explicit history of undoing the commits.